# Execute function within the constructor call

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constructor

What I would like to achieve is the following: I want to allow the users to only create objects of class A if they provide a function - this function may construct and calculate things and set other members of the object. In short, I need a way to only allow a constructor call that includes a function as an argument that is subsequently executed with said constructor call. Imagining it like filling those blanks right now:

```
void foo()
{
// do something
}


class A
{
public:
    A(/*magic*/);

/*
...
*/


A:A()
{
    /*magic*/
}
```

I have read about function pointers but have yet to figure out what this syntax:

```
int (*const fcnPtr)();
```

translates into and how I can achieve what I want to achieve with it - assuming this is the "best" way in the first place.

Whatever closes the chain of **function definition -> constructor call with link to function -> executing the function during object construction** is of interest to me.

Thank you for reading and thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: Replace `A:A()` with `A::A()`

Comment: Function pointer will probably work, but also look into [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: @user4581301 That also works, but requires a `virtual` call. You can spare that using templates.

Comment: Likely we're reading the question differently, @lorro . I don't see a need for `virtual`.

Comment: @user4581301 It's inside `std::function`. How would you implement generic type erasure in C++ without `virtual` (or function pointers, which are essentially the same)?

Comment: Question: If I said "I want to allow the users to only create objects of class A if they provide a number - this number may be any whole number from 1 to 999999. In short, I need a way to only allow a constructor call that includes a number as an argument that is subsequently printed with said constructor call" would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is by a template:

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;

    template<typename F>
    A(F f)
    : i(0) /* and other initializers*/
    { f(); } // no need to pass *this, see below
};

// usage:
A a([&]() { a.i = 0; });
```

Comment: thank you! I adapted this approach, but I would like to achieve a more general constructor: It would be perfect if I would give an arbitrary function AND another parameter of arbitrary type with it - but just throwing in another template argument is not possible. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Rosenkohl435834 You might have any number of arguments beside the template argument (like, `template<typename F> A(F f, int i, long j, double g)`). You might also forward these to the function - albeit you might also bind the parameters at the call point.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your given example, you can add a function pointer as parameter of the constructor:

```
void foo()
{
  std::cout <<" foo called" << std::endl;
}
void bar()
{
    std::cout << "bar called" << std::endl;
}


class A
{
public:
//-----------vvv------->ptr is a pointer to a function that has no parameter and return type void 
    A(void (*ptr)());

};


A::A(void (*ptr)())
{
    //call through ptr 
    ptr(); 
}
int main()
{
    A a(foo); //this will call foo 
    
    A b(bar); //this will cal bar
}
```

Comment: This works, but is expected to be slower than templates (depending on the optimizer) if it's not in the same compilation unit.

Comment: @lorro Yes, I'm just showing an alternate way of doing this without saying whether it is the best way or not. The more examples OP see, the more they'll learn.

Comment: @lorro if it's template, it can't even in different compilation unit though. (yes I know it's possible in some case)

Comment: @JasonLiam Agree that it's better to list multiple solutions. I mentioned the performance only so it's known ahead.